# jQuery ".then()" is not sequent, and working not as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I need to call three functions one by one.
For this purpose i am using jquery deferred "then" to chain the calls.

Here is the code:

```
function fillQuantity(x){
    console.log('Q');
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    
    var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        console.log("Quantity: ", x);    
        deferred.resolve();
    }, 2000);
    
    return deferred.promise();
};

function fillPrice(x){
    console.log('P');
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    
    var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        console.log("Price: ", x);    
        deferred.resolve();
    }, 2000);
    
    return deferred.promise();
};

function fillSection(x){
    console.log('S');
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    
    var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        console.log("Section: ", x);    
        deferred.resolve();
    }, 2000);
    
    return deferred.promise();
};

var promise = jQuery.when().promise();

promise = promise.then(fillQuantity).then(fillPrice).then(fillSection);

promise.done(function(){
    console.log('done');
});
```

In this case i supposed to have following output:

> Q
>
> Quantity:  undefined
>
> P
>
> Price:  undefined
>
> S
>
> Section:  undefined
>
> done

But in fact I have received:

> Q
>
> P
>
> S
>
> done
>
> Quantity:  undefined
>
> Price:  undefined
>
> Section:  undefined

As I see jQuery calls all three functions and ignore promise resolving.
What I am doing wrong? Or what I don't know about jquery promises?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're calling `$.when()` without arguments instead of issuing `fillQuantity().then(fillPrice).then(fillSection)`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$.when(fillQuantity, fillPrice, ...).then()`?

Comment: there is no reason for calling $.when() without arguments, i just need a promise to make a chain of calls.

Comment: This code 
jQuery.when(fillQuantity, fillPrice, fillSection).then(function(){
    console.log('ok');
}) 

doesn't work. It prints 'ok'.. and that is all.

Comment: @Jack, that would not chain the calls, all the `fillXXX()` methods would be called without waiting for the previous promise to be resolved.

Comment: how need i refactor code to make it wait for promise resolving? In Promises/A+ chain work perfect, but not in jQuery..

Comment: I don't know why, but your code works fine here http://plnkr.co/edit/LgX9N5?p=preview

Comment: Really weird. I have tested in Chrome console. May be version of jQuery matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be issue was in jQuery version.

1.6.1 - works incorrectly.
2.0.3 - works as expected

jQuery 1.6.1 was released when promises were new. And it was buggy.

It looks like it was fixed/changed around 1.8.3.

1.7.1 failed the tests as well;

Comment: This answer is correct as per issue described. So, if you do not understand, do not vote down.

Comment: pro100sanya, yes I can confirm your findings. OK from jQuery 1.8.3 . In earlier versions `.then(fn)` behaved like `.done(fn)`, ie propagated the state of the input promise, not the promise returned by the function.

Comment: By the way, with `deferred.resolve(x);` in the three functions, and starting the chain with an input value, eg `var promise = fillQuantity(99).then(fillPrice).then(fillSection);`, you should see that value propagate through. The `undefined`s will become 99s.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend considering using a es6 compliant promise implementation.

An immense amount of work has gone into the es6 promises specification to ensure correctness, which helps prevent these types of shortcomings. Unfortunately the jQuery ones can currently cause much grief. (like the problem you mention)

Additionally, some (and soon other) evergreen browsers will come with such an implementation.
For now using a polyfil is likely appropriate. I would suggest looking at https://github.com/jakearchibald/ES6-Promises

Anyways, I have refactored your example to work with any of the es6 compliant implementations, and it now it works as expected.

```
function fillQuantity(x){
  console.log('Q');

  return new Promise(function(resolve){
    var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      console.log("Quantity: ", x);
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });
};

function fillPrice(x){
  console.log('P');

  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        console.log("Price: ", x);
        resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });
};

function fillSection(x){
  console.log('S');

  return new Promise(function(resolve){

    var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        console.log("Section: ", x);
        resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });
};

var promise = Promise.resolve();

promise.
  then(fillQuantity).
  then(fillPrice).
  then(fillSection).
  then(function(){
    console.log('done');
  });
```

output:

```
Quantity: undefined
P
Price:  undefined
S
Section:  undefined
done
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly, i need to add another promise library and use their own Promises, not a jquery promises?